# How to Unit Test an Implementation of IDictionary

Tags: c#, unit-testing

When implementing something that implements IDictionary, what should I unit test?

It seems to be overkill to test the entire interface, but then what do I know?  I have only been unit testing for a few days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every public member of your IDictionary should be tested. You should also set up some tests to ensure that your IDictionary behaves the same as some other concrete implementation of an IDictionary. In fact, you could structure most of your tests like that:

```
void Test_IDictionary_Add(IDictionary a, IDictionary b)
{
    string key = "Key1", badKey = 87;
    int value = 9, badValue = "Horse";

    a.Add(key, value);
    b.Add(key, value);

    Assert.That(a.Count, Is.EqualTo(b.Count));
    Assert.That(a.Contains(key), Is.EqualTo(b.Contains(key)));
    Assert.That(a.ContainsKey(key), Is.EqualTo(b.ContainsKey(key)));
    Assert.That(a.ContainsValue(value), Is.EqualTo(b.ContainsValue(value)));
    Assert.That(a.Contains(badKey), Is.EqualTo(b.Contains(badKey)));
    Assert.That(a.ContainsValue(badValue), Is.EqualTo(b.ContainsValue(badValue)));
    // ... and so on and so forth
}

[Test]
void MyDictionary_Add()
{
    Test_IDictionary_Add(new MyDictionary(), new Hashtable());
}
```

Comment: Nice, thorough, specific answer.

Comment: Not according to Brian (see comments).

Comment: (Chris B) He is not testing the framework. He is testing that the implementation of the interface (MyDictionary) is doing what he expects it to... that is, act like a Hashtable.  This is more about testing the BEHAVIOR of the interface, but not testing Hashtable itself.

Comment: Just to be clear, what sixletter is suggesting is not the way that I was suggesting writing unit tests in my answer.  I think that a sanity test like this is useful, but I believe that unit tests should be smaller, more concise tests of specific behaviors.

Comment: I would advocate both Brian's and mine. Brian's will pick up "duh" problems. Mine will (possibly) pick up more subtle issues. Brian's will require you to say what you expect. Mine assumes somebody else got it right, so "monkey see monkey do" == correct.

Comment: Minor point, but is there a typo at `Assert.That(a.Contains(key), Is.EqualTo(a.ContainsKey(key)));` ? I edited the answer, please rollback if not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should test everything you implement.  If you have code that is called through the public interface, there should be a unit test that supports that.  If you write the code, it is worth testing.

The exception might be simple properties ( Property {get; set;} )

Comment: Absolutely what? Are you saying he should write a specific test for each member of IDictionary? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary_members.aspx. That's tantamount to "[testing] the framework," as Chris says.

Comment: That is not at all "testing the framework". If you write code that implements the interface, you should write tests that tests your implementation. You are not, in any way, testing the framework in that case. You are testing YOUR code.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're saying. Tests that test your implementation, yes, but are you advocating writing individual tests for each member of the interface (e.g. "the entire interface")?

Comment: Yes.  That is what unit tests are.  They test the functionality of your code through the public interface.  If you implement a method on the interface, it should have a test.  Are you suggesting that you implement something on the interface (ie. write code) and not write tests?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand common unit testing practices better. :)

Comment: No problem.  Testing the framework would be writing tests against Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, which there is no reason to do.  In the OP's question, he wants to test MyDictionary : IDictionary.  In that case you want to test the crap out of it to make sure it conforms to the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Test all your interface points, but beware the temptation to test the framework.

Comment: What do you consider "interface points?" The IDictionary members his code uses?

Comment: Anything he has written other than basic get/set/instantiate

Answer (score 0):

You should test all the members exposed by your interface.

Here below is a routine I call to test my objects which implement `IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`. This is in **VB.Net**, but I thought someone might find it useful.

Note: If you are dealing with collections of objects rather than structures, you might want to use an overload of `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` which allows to define an `IComparer`.

### Test Method

```
Public Sub TestBatch_SomeContext()

    Dim TestedDictionary As IDictionary(Of Integer, String) = New ObjectDictionary()
    Dim ControlDictionary As IDictionary(Of Integer, String) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim MyTestingSet As New TestingRoutines.Collections.Testing_IDictionary(Of Integer, String)(ControlDictionary, TestedDictionary)

    Dim SomeKeys() As Integer = {8, 3, 4, 1, 12, 45, 98, 65}
    Dim SomeValues() As String = {"mopet", "789", "%*+", "15/12/1995", "", "Europe", "abcd", "okay"}
    Dim OtherKeys() As Integer = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 101}
    Dim OtherValues() As String = {"a value?", "words in here", "06/01/2010", "something", "Europe", "voila"}
    MyTestingSet.TestFullBatch(SomeKeys, SomeValues, OtherKeys, OtherValues)

End Sub
```

### Generic Testing Routine

```
Namespace TestingRoutines.Collections


    ''' <summary>
    ''' A testing routine which compares the state of a tested dictionary (not trusted) against the state of control dictionary (trusted), after applying the same operations to both.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <typeparam name="TKey">The type of keys in the dictionary.</typeparam>
    ''' <typeparam name="TValue">The type of values in the dictionary.</typeparam>
    Public Class Testing_IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The trusted dictionary implementation to verify the tests against.
        ''' </summary>
        Public ReadOnly Property ControlDict As IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The non-trusted dictionary implementation to be tested.
        ''' </summary>
        Public ReadOnly Property TestedDict As IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Exoses a set of generic tests.
        ''' </summary>
        Private ReadOnly Property GenericTests As New GenericTests(Of IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue))


        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Creates a new instance of a testing routine which compares the state of a tested dictionary (not trusted) against the state of control dictionary (trusted), after applying the same operations to both.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="ControlDict">The trusted dictionary implementation to verify the tests against.</param>
        ''' <param name="TestedDict">The non-trusted dictionary implementation to be tested.</param>
        Public Sub New(ControlDict As IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue), TestedDict As IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
            Me.ControlDict = ControlDict
            Me.TestedDict = TestedDict
        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Runs the complete set of tests available in the testing routine.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="SomeKeys">The keys of some items to be added in the dictionary. Minimum 6 items; all keys must be unique.</param>
        ''' <param name="SomeValues">The values of some items to be added in the dictionary. There must be as many values as item keys.</param>
        ''' <param name="OtherKeys">The keys of some items which are different from the items to be added in the dictionary. Minimum 6 items; all keys must be unique.</param>
        ''' <param name="OtherValues">The values of some items which are different from the items to be added in the dictionary. there must be as many values as item keys</param>
        Public Sub TestFullBatch(SomeKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), SomeValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue), OtherKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), OtherValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue))

            Dim MinAddCount As Integer = 6
            If SomeKeys.Count < MinAddCount Then Throw New ArgumentException($"This test requires at least {MinAddCount} item keys to be added.", NameOf(SomeKeys))
            If SomeKeys.Count <> SomeValues.Count Then Throw New ArgumentException("There must be as many item values as item keys to be added.", NameOf(SomeValues))
            If SomeKeys.Any(Function(p) SomeKeys.Count(Function(q) p.Equals(q)) > 1) Then Throw New ArgumentException("The collection of item keys to be added cannot contain duplicates.", NameOf(SomeKeys))

            Dim MinNotAddedCount As Integer = 6
            If OtherKeys.Count < MinNotAddedCount Then Throw New ArgumentException($"This test requires at least {MinNotAddedCount} item keys to be tested as not added.", NameOf(OtherKeys))
            If OtherKeys.Count <> OtherValues.Count Then Throw New ArgumentException("There must be as many item values as item keys to be tested as not added.", NameOf(OtherValues))
            If OtherKeys.Any(Function(p) OtherKeys.Count(Function(q) p.Equals(q)) > 1) Then Throw New ArgumentException("The collection of item keys to be tested as not added cannot contain duplicates.", NameOf(OtherKeys))
            If OtherKeys.Any(Function(p) SomeKeys.Contains(p)) Then Throw New ArgumentException("The item keys to be tested as not added cannot appear in the list of item keys to be added.", NameOf(OtherKeys))


            IsReadOnly()

            Add(SomeKeys, SomeValues, OtherKeys, OtherValues)

            Remove(SomeKeys.Skip(1).Take(2))
            Remove(SomeKeys.Reverse.Take(2))

            Clear()

            AddItem(SomeKeys, SomeValues, OtherKeys, OtherValues)

            RemoveItem(SomeKeys.Take(2), SomeValues.Take(2))
            RemoveItem(SomeKeys.Reverse.Skip(2).Take(2), SomeValues.Reverse.Skip(2).Take(2))

            Dim ArrayKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey) = OtherKeys.Take(MinNotAddedCount - 2).ToArray
            Dim ArrayValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue) = OtherValues.Take(MinNotAddedCount - 2).ToArray
            CopyTo(ArrayKeys, ArrayValues, MinNotAddedCount - 4)

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the IsReadOnly property.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub IsReadOnly()

            Assert.AreEqual(Me.TestedDict.IsReadOnly, Me.ControlDict.IsReadOnly)

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the Add(Key, Value) method.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="AddKeys">The item keys to add.</param>
        ''' <param name="AddValues">The item values to add.</param>
        ''' <param name="NotAddedKeys">The item keys which are expected not be included in the dictionary.</param>
        ''' <param name="NotAddedValues">The item values which are expected not to be included in the dictionary.</param>
        Public Sub Add(AddKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), AddValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue), NotAddedKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), NotAddedValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue))

            Dim MyKeyEnum As IEnumerator(Of TKey) = AddKeys.GetEnumerator
            Dim MyValueEnum As IEnumerator(Of TValue) = AddValues.GetEnumerator

            Do While MyKeyEnum.MoveNext And MyValueEnum.MoveNext
                Dim MyKey As TKey = MyKeyEnum.Current
                Dim MyValue As TValue = MyValueEnum.Current
                Me.ControlDict.Add(MyKey, MyValue)
                Me.TestedDict.Add(MyKey, MyValue)
            Loop

            TestBasicContents()

            TestItem(AddKeys.First, AddValues.First)
            TestItem(AddKeys.Last, AddValues.Last)
            TestItem(NotAddedKeys.First, NotAddedValues.First)
            TestItem(NotAddedKeys.Last, NotAddedValues.Last)

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the Add(KeyValuePair) method.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="AddKeys">The item keys to add.</param>
        ''' <param name="AddValues">The item values to add.</param>
        ''' <param name="NotAddedKeys">The item keys which are expected not to be included in the dictionary.</param>
        ''' <param name="NotAddedValues">The item values which are expected not to be included in the dictionary.</param>
        Public Sub AddItem(AddKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), AddValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue), NotAddedKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), NotAddedValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue))

            Dim MyKeyEnum As IEnumerator(Of TKey) = AddKeys.GetEnumerator
            Dim MyValueEnum As IEnumerator(Of TValue) = AddValues.GetEnumerator
            Do While MyKeyEnum.MoveNext And MyValueEnum.MoveNext
                Dim MyKey As TKey = MyKeyEnum.Current
                Dim MyValue As TValue = MyValueEnum.Current
                Dim KeyValue As New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(MyKey, MyValue)
                Me.ControlDict.Add(KeyValue)
                Me.TestedDict.Add(KeyValue)
            Loop

            TestBasicContents()

            TestItem(AddKeys.First, AddValues.First)
            TestItem(AddKeys.Last, AddValues.Last)
            TestItem(NotAddedKeys.First, NotAddedValues.First)
            TestItem(NotAddedKeys.Last, NotAddedValues.Last)

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the Remove(Key) method.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="RemoveKeys">The item keys of the items to remove.</param>
        Public Sub Remove(RemoveKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey))

            For Each MyKey As TKey In RemoveKeys
                Me.ControlDict.Remove(MyKey)
                Me.TestedDict.Remove(MyKey)
            Next

            TestBasicContents()

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the Remove(KeyValuePair) method.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="RemoveKeys">The item keys to remove.</param>
        ''' <param name="RemoveValues">The item values to remove.</param>
        Public Sub RemoveItem(RemoveKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), RemoveValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue))

            Dim MyKeyEnum As IEnumerator(Of TKey) = RemoveKeys.GetEnumerator
            Dim MyValueEnum As IEnumerator(Of TValue) = RemoveValues.GetEnumerator

            Do While MyKeyEnum.MoveNext And MyValueEnum.MoveNext
                Dim MyKey As TKey = MyKeyEnum.Current
                Dim MyValue As TValue = MyValueEnum.Current
                Dim KeyValue As New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(MyKey, MyValue)
                Me.ControlDict.Remove(KeyValue)
                Me.TestedDict.Remove(KeyValue)
            Loop

            TestBasicContents()

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the Clear() method.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub Clear()

            Me.ControlDict.Clear()
            Me.TestedDict.Clear()

            TestBasicContents()

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies the CopyTo(array(), arrayIndex) method.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="ArrayKeys">The collection of item keys to include in the list of KeyValuePairs to copy from..</param>
        ''' <param name="ArrayValues">The collection of item values to include in the list of KeyValuePairs to copy from.</param>
        ''' <param name="ArrayIndex">The zero-based array index at which copying will begin.</param>
        Public Sub CopyTo(ArrayKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), ArrayValues As IEnumerable(Of TValue), ArrayIndex As Integer)

            Dim MyCollection As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue))

            Dim MyKeyEnum As IEnumerator(Of TKey) = ArrayKeys.GetEnumerator
            Dim MyValueEnum As IEnumerator(Of TValue) = ArrayValues.GetEnumerator
            Do While MyKeyEnum.MoveNext And MyValueEnum.MoveNext
                Dim MyKey As TKey = MyKeyEnum.Current
                Dim MyValue As TValue = MyValueEnum.Current
                Dim KeyValue As New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(MyKey, MyValue)
                MyCollection.Add(KeyValue)
            Loop

            Dim MyControlArray(99) As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) ' <- Note: Fixed size array
            Dim MyTestingArray(99) As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) ' <- Note: Fixed size array
            MyCollection.CopyTo(MyControlArray, 0)
            MyCollection.CopyTo(MyTestingArray, 0)

            Me.ControlDict.CopyTo(MyControlArray, ArrayIndex)
            Me.TestedDict.CopyTo(MyTestingArray, ArrayIndex)

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(MyControlArray, MyTestingArray)

        End Sub


#Region "Helpers"


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies state equality of the control and tested dictionaries. This is achieved by comparing the Count, Keys, and Values properties.
        ''' </summary>
        Private Sub TestBasicContents()

            Assert.AreEqual(Me.ControlDict.Count, Me.TestedDict.Count)
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(Me.ControlDict.Keys.ToList, Me.TestedDict.Keys.ToList)
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(Me.ControlDict.Values.ToList, Me.TestedDict.Values.ToList)

        End Sub


        ''' <summary>
        ''' Verifies behaviour equality of the control and tested dictionaries, for a given item. This is achieved by comparing the ContainsKey(Key), Contains(KeyValuePair), TryGetValue(Key, Value)
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="Key">The key of the item to look for.</param>
        ''' <param name="Value">The value of the item to look for.</param>
        Private Sub TestItem(Key As TKey, Value As TValue)

            Dim KeyValue As New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(Key, Value)

            Assert.AreEqual(Me.ControlDict.ContainsKey(Key), Me.TestedDict.ContainsKey(Key))
            Assert.AreEqual(Me.ControlDict.Contains(KeyValue), Me.TestedDict.Contains(KeyValue))

            Dim MyControlVal As TValue
            Dim MyTestingVal As TValue
            Assert.AreEqual(Me.ControlDict.TryGetValue(Key, MyControlVal), Me.TestedDict.TryGetValue(Key, MyTestingVal))
            Assert.AreEqual(MyControlVal, MyTestingVal)

            GenericTests.TestExceptionBehaviour(Me.ControlDict, Me.TestedDict, Function(p) p.Item(Key))
            GenericTests.TestExceptionBehaviour(Me.ControlDict, Me.TestedDict, Sub(p) p.Item(Key) = Value)
            GenericTests.TestExceptionBehaviour(Me.ControlDict, Me.TestedDict, Sub(p) p.Add(Key, Value))
            GenericTests.TestExceptionBehaviour(Me.ControlDict, Me.TestedDict, Sub(p) p.Add(KeyValue))
            GenericTests.TestExceptionBehaviour(Me.ControlDict, Me.TestedDict, Function(p) p.Remove(Key))
            GenericTests.TestExceptionBehaviour(Me.ControlDict, Me.TestedDict, Function(p) p.Remove(KeyValue))

        End Sub


#End Region


    End Class


End Namespace
```

### Additional Helper

```
Namespace TestingRoutines

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Exposes a set of generic tests.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to be tested.</typeparam>
    Public Class GenericTests(Of T)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Exposes a set of  generic tests.
        ''' </summary>
        Sub New()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Asserts a given action on a tested object throws an exception, when and only when the same action on a control object triggers an exception of that same type.
        ''' <para>Note only the exception types are verified, not the content of their message or exception code.</para>
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="ControlObject">The trusted object to compare the behaviour with.</param>
        ''' <param name="TestedObject">The non-trusted object to be tested.</param>
        ''' <param name="Action">The tested action on the objects.</param>
        Public Sub TestExceptionBehaviour(ControlObject As T, TestedObject As T, Action As Action(Of T))

            Dim ControlThrowedException As Boolean

            Try
                ControlThrowedException = True
                Action.Invoke(ControlObject)
                ControlThrowedException = False
                Action.Invoke(TestedObject)
            Catch ex As Exception
                If Not ControlThrowedException Then Assert.Fail($"Unexpected exception. The tested object threw an exception whilst the control object did not: {ex.ToString}")
                Try
                    Action.Invoke(TestedObject)
                    Assert.Fail($"Expected exception. The control object threw an exception whilst the tested object did not: {ex.ToString}")
                Catch ex2 As Exception
                    If ex.GetType <> ex2.GetType Then Assert.Fail($"Exception types mismatch. The control object threw an exception of type '{ex.GetType.ToString}' whilst the tested object threw an exception of type '{ex2.GetType.ToString}'.")
                End Try
            End Try

        End Sub

    End Class


End Namespace
```